# Upsert everynow and then creates a duplicate

Tags: developer, upsert

Every now and then I have a duplicate account been created from a piece of code that looks like the one below, where there is only 1 upsert in the whole code.

I am wondering why sometimes it creates a duplicate, will this be random salesforce error?

```
Account acc = new Account();
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
Contact con = new Contact();
List<Account> accLST = new List<Account>();
accLST = [SELECT .. FROM Account WHERE ...];
....
if (accLST.size() > 1) {
    pageError = '....';
    return;
} else if (accLST.size() == 1) {
    acc = accLST[0];
} else {
    createAcc = true;
}


acc.field1__c = ...;
acc.field2__c = ...;
upsert acc;
....
....
upsert con;
....
....
upsert opp;
```

Below the time stamps of the account been created nearly simultaneously

[image: timestamp of record]

I am wondering if it will be best to split this with something like

```
if (acc.Id != null) {
    update acc;
} else {
    insert acc;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not accidentally double-clicking the save button?

Comment: @sfdcfox I though in that, the problem  is this is in a vf page that I dont have control on it, as multiple people use it, I have tried testing but never been success on recreating this, perhaps i am unable to click that fast, if this is the case what action would you recommend to take to avoid this duplicate, considering that they will move to a "second page"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this **will not help you**. The users are double-clicking the button, and the system runs the code twice. Because of the nature of how Visualforce works, the same view state data is submitted twice to the server, resulting in two executions that occur in parallel on the same data. The only solution is to modify the Visualforce page to block the second click before it can make it to the server. Something like this:

```
<apex:commandButton onclick="this.disabled=true" 
    action="{!save}" oncomplete="this.disabled=false" />
```